# jQuery is missing in wp-admin

Tags: jquery, wp-admin

I have downloaded all wordpress project folder from production server. Also changed the website URL to local one and logged in as an admin, but somehow jQuery is missing in wp-admin. What can gone wrong?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE!**

Tejas Gajjar suggestions for wp-config menu started showing. But jQuery still not found - so UI can not work properly!

Problem nr.2 - Add Post and Edit Post loads empty page...